# Issue with Rspec Timer test

Tags: ruby, class, time, rspec, numbers

I am stuck in second gear, please review my code and give me some input. Thank you.

```
class Timer
    def initialize(seconds = 0,time_string = "00:00:00")
        @seconds = seconds
        @time_string = time_string

    end

    def seconds=(new_sec)
        @seconds = new_sec
    end

    def seconds
        @seconds
    end

    def time_string=(new_time)

        hh = seconds/3600
        mm = seconds%3600/60
        ss = seconds%60
        new_time = "#{hh}:#{mm}:#{ss}" 
        @time_string = new_time 
    end

    def time_string
        @time_string
    end
end
```

Rspec:

```
require 'timer'

describe "Timer" do
  before(:each) do
    @timer = Timer.new
  end

  it "should initialize to 0 seconds" do
    @timer.seconds.should == 0
  end

  describe 'time_string' do
    it "should display 0 seconds as 00:00:00" do
    @timer.seconds = 0
    @timer.time_string.should == "00:00:00"
  end

  it "should display 12 seconds as 00:00:12" do

    @timer.seconds = 12
    @timer.time_string.should == "00:00:12"
  end

  it "should display 66 seconds as 00:01:06" do
    @timer.seconds = 66
    @timer.time_string.should == "00:01:06"
  end

  it "should display 4000 seconds as 01:06:40" do
    @timer.seconds = 4000
    @timer.time_string.should == "01:06:40"
  end
end
```

Comment: This may be better on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ (assuming the code works). For this to be answered on Stack Overflow, please describe a specific problem you are having.

Comment: Asa quick clue however, to match the test behaviour, you should not set or store `@time_string`, just calculate it on demand.

Comment: What course is this from?  lots of people asking the same question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is an assignment `def time_string=(new_time)` but you're not actually using new_time to change the value of anything, so better to say `def time_string` to define a getter only.  (Your tests don't indicate that you want the ability to set time via a supplied time_string.)

And as Neil Slater points out you don't need to have an instance variable @time_string, just return new_time from the time_string method and you have what you want. So your code...

```
def time_string=(new_time)

        hh = seconds/3600
        mm = seconds%3600/60
        ss = seconds%60
        new_time = "#{hh}:#{mm}:#{ss}" 
        @time_string = new_time 
    end
```

replace with

```
def time_string
  hh = @seconds/3600
  mm = @seconds%3600/60
  ss = @seconds%60
  new_time = "#{hh}:#{mm}:#{ss}" 
end
```

Comment: Got it. Thanks. My solution is to replace the new_time with: new_time = [hh,mm,ss].map { |e| e.to_s.rjust(2,'0') }.join ':'